How to disable addition of tenantId for a entity or query[Spring boot - Hibernate]
I am doing multitenant integration using @TenantId notation.
How can I prevent tenantid from being added to queries for only a entity?
TenantIdentifierResolver class
@Component
public class CurrentTenantIdentifierResolverImpl implements CurrentTenantIdentifierResolver, HibernatePropertiesCustomizer {

    @Override
    public Long resolveCurrentTenantIdentifier() {
        return ContextHolder.getCurrentContext().getUserContext().getTenantId();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean validateExistingCurrentSessions() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void customize(Map<String, Object> hibernateProperties) {
        hibernateProperties.put(AvailableSettings.MULTI_TENANT_IDENTIFIER_RESOLVER, this);
    }
}

BaseEntity class
import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.MappedSuperclass;
import org.hibernate.annotations.TenantId;

@MappedSuperclass
public class BaseEntity {
    @Column(name = "tenant_id")
    @TenantId
    protected Long tenantId;

    ...
}

Permission Entity
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "PERMISSION")
public class Permission extends BaseEntity {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;

    ...
}

Example Query
@Query("select p from Permission p where p.tenantId = :tenantId and p.username=:username")
List<Permission> findPermissionByTenantIdAndUsername(@Param("tenantId") Long tenantId, @Param("username") String username);

In the above query, tenantId is added to the where condition twice. In some of my queries, I need to query specifically for tenantId, so how can I prevent tenantid from being automatically added to queries?
